# derivative of composite functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $F(x,y,z)=0$. Assuming that this can be solved for z in terms of $(x,y)$, find expressions for $(\partial)^2z)/\partial(x^2)$ and $(\partial)^2z)/\partial(x)\partial(y)$ in terms of F and its derivatives

For first step i found $\partial(z)/\partial(x)=-(F_1/F_3)$ and $\partial(z)/\partial(y)=-(F_2/F_3)$. But then i cannot found which strategy should i follow. May anyone help me?

Comment: I recommend looking at the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)

Comment: thank you, but i indeed i tried to solve it by İmplicit Function Theorem but i couldn't get out of it.

Comment: Well assuming that the 2nd order partial derivatives of  your function $z:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ exist, you can simply use implicit differentiation, quotient rule and chain rule.

Comment: Thank you, eventually i solved it. But i use F_13=F_31 at the end. for the same answer with book is it true?